# Adding .navigationTitle to view in NavigationStack is breaking animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm trying to create a view that shows a list of items / overview in one state and a detail for a selected list item in another state, and I'd like to show a hero animation when switching between those two states. I'd also like to show a navigation title when in the "overview" state, so I'm wrapping everything in a `NavigationStack`. However, I have an issue on iOS 17 / Xcode 15 where the `.navigationTitle` is breaking the animation between the "overview" and "detail" views. For some reason, the sub-view "jumps" while adding/removing the navigation title.

Here is a very simple version of what I'm trying to do:

```swift
import SwiftUI 

@MainActor
final class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published private(set) var flag = false
  
  func toggleFlag() {
    flag.toggle()
  }
}

struct TestView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: TestViewModel
  @Namespace private var animation

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      VStack {
        if viewModel.flag {
          // the "detail" state
          VStack {
            circle
            text
            switchButton
          }
        } else {
          // the "overview / list" state
          VStack {
            circle
            switchButton
          }
          .navigationTitle("Title")
        }
      }
    }
  }


  private var switchButton: some View {
    Button("switch") {
      withAnimation {
        viewModel.toggleFlag()
      }
    }
    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Button", in: animation)
  }
  
  private var circle: some View {
    Circle()
      .fill(.red)
      .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
      .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Shape", in: animation)
  }
  
  private var text: some View {
    Text("Taylor Switch - 1989")
      .font(.headline)
  }
}
```

The `.matchedGeometryEffect` appears to be working: when the "detail" is shown, the circle and button animate as if they're making space for the text in the middle, and when "overview" view is shown, the circle and button animate as if they're moving into the void left by the text. If you remove the `.navigationTitle`, you'll also notice that the animation appears to work correctly. The issue seems to be present regardless of whether `.matchedGeometryEffect` is present or not.

For some reason, it's like the transition between a sub-view with a navigation title and one without a navigation title is not being animated and is causing the "jump" effect. If you look closely, you'll actually notice that the navigation title does not fade in or out.

I did find [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/728132) on the Apple forums, but the solution did not seem to work for my case, and I also saw that someone else commented the issue was fixed in Xcode 15, so I don't think I have the same issue.

## Video Demos

Here are two gifs, one where `navigationTitle` is applied and one where it isn't:

[example of broken animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXmGT.gif)

[example of animation without navigation title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uj20.gif)

Comment: "I'm trying to create a view that shows a list of items / overview in one state and a detail for a selected list item in another state" That's the job of a `NavigationLink`. Why aren't you using that?

Comment: @Sweeper I'm not using a NavigationLink specifically because I want to show a hero animation, and as far as I know you're unable to customize the transition animation for a NavigationLink.